# ArcGIS Server: secured service attachment not referencing token

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, feature-layer, attachments

I have built several applications that use the ArcGIS JS API and secured services via ArcGIS Server.  All of the apps have the same process of generating tokens on the server ( via php request ) and passed to the client where it is appended to the service urls.  Recently we have noticed an issue when we attempt to upload an attachment.  When the `addattachment` method is called the request is sent to the login page for ArcGIS Server.  It appears that the request is not honoring the token.

Anyone run into this issue before?  I have tried a proxy and `esrirequest` to modify the request but still doesn't work.  I have also signed into ArcGIS Server and was able to upload an attachment through the GUI form there so the service is working.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. It's impossible to determine what is wrong if you don't provide code and some diagnostics of what your HTTP traffic looks like. Please [Edit] the question.

Comment: @Booshwa, what has changed on the server recently? Did you federate with ArcGIS Portal? Has the machine been assigned a DNS alias? Did the Feature Service Url in the application change? Did you change authentication (assuming you have a web adaptor installed)?

Comment: We have implemented SSL which is the only thing that has changed.  The service has been in use for a couple years and I have tested by uploading files through the feature service in ArcGIS Server (through the web adapter)  We haven't changed anything on ArcGIS in several months.

Comment: I'll post as much as I can from the network panel and fiddler but I cannot share the app or the service URL as soon as I can.  I can post some code but it's just the featurelayer calling the 'addattachment' method.  Nothing custom there.

Comment: If you are using the php proxy from https://github.com/Esri/resource-proxy, there are a few open related issues reported in the github repo - https://github.com/Esri/resource-proxy/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aopen%20attachment%20.  Including an open pull request: https://github.com/Esri/resource-proxy/pull/365 - does it work if you try that code?

Answer (score 1):

This should be resolved now that https://github.com/Esri/resource-proxy/pull/365 has been merged.